# ADC not working

Tags: adc

I am using a MCP3008 ADC connected to the Raspberry Pi SPI pins.

- MOSI → MOSI,
- MISO → MISO,
- CE0 → ~(CS),
- CLK → SPI_SCLK

Input voltage to MCP3008 is 3.3V from the RPi. Vref also 3.3. GNDs all connected to ground rail on breadboard. Analog inputs 1-7 are wired directly to GND (should be 0's). Channel 0 is connected directly to 3.3V to obtain a full 1023 reading.

When observing the output of the ADC on the RPi, I am seeing lots of noisy data across all channels and Channel 0 is not 1023 but random values between 0-1023. It appears the ADC is not correctly translating the 3.3V on channel 0 to a solid 1023 and it is also getting values for the grounded channels 1-7.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I am using all brand new out of the box parts to eliminate the possibility of damaged connections. Also, I have metered all inputs and outputs on the ADC to RPi and all check out as working except the Dout pin on the ADC (MISO). The MISO pin from the ADC reads approximately 1.6V when it should output 3.3V since Ch.0 is connected to 3.3V.

Comment: In your question, you said "MOSI -> MOSI, MISO -> MISO" but there are no pins on the ADC labelled that according to the datasheet; I assume you mean Dout -> MISO, and Din <- MOSI.

Comment: What software are you using to read the values from the ADC?

Comment: Python script to read the ADC values

Comment: Yes, I would have guessed that. Can you be a *little* more specific? For example, are you following the [Adafruit tutorial](https://learn.adafruit.com/reading-a-analog-in-and-controlling-audio-volume-with-the-raspberry-pi?view=all)?

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Yes I am using Adafruit's method of implementing the ADC. The spidev library not bit-banging the SPI connection.

Comment: How can you be using Adafruit's method and not use bit banging? Why don't you try bit banging just to see if anything sensible is coming out? What else is different about your setup?

Comment: well Adafruit is doing it all behind the scenes using functions from their library. The thing is, just last week everything was working fine and the same code, same setup, same wires, and same power and now it just is not working properly. The data that comes out is not sensible, it is very noisy even with a direct Vcc input to Channel 0 (the one channel I am reading). Also, Channels 1-7 get values as well even though all these channels are GROUNDED.

Comment: ok so I have consistent 0 readings across all channels (used 330 Ohm resistors to GND for Channels 1-7). Channel 0 is still wired to Vcc (3.3V) and it reads "0" as well. I believe the issue is not down to faulty wires, SPI connection issue (using Adafruit library/code), or ADC Dout.

Comment: I tried a 3rd brand new breadboard, and 3rd set of brand new wires and now I am receiving 1023 across channel 0 like expected. I believe the issue was the wires (bought from China). I just checked again on my last breadboard (2nd of the 3 boards I used) and I only swapped the SPI wires and now it works. It was a wire issue. Faulty Wires... thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

- Multimeter check voltages of all inputs and outputs from RPi and ADC are what they should be = still "0" as the readings
- Reprogrammed ADC using Python using Adafruit's library as well as bit-banging = still "0's"
- Created replica circuit with all new out of the box components = still "0's"
- Replaced wires on circuit used for SPI communication = SOLUTION!!!

I had to go through a few wires before I found working connections. THAT'S WHAT I GET BUYING WIRES FROM FOREIGN COUNTRIES (china)!!